# Kotlin Cinterops native library name

Tags: kotlin, multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I'm using cinterops to link a dynamic library in a mingw binary executable. Everything is working fine, except that the .dll name that the executable asks is different from the one declared at the .def file.
I don't know where this different name is coming from!
This is from my gradle.build.kts:

```
mingwX86("mingw"){
    compilations["main"].cinterops{
        val scape2 by creating {
            val cafmSrc = "C:/Software/SCAP E2/CAFM_src"
            val scapSrc = "C:/Software/SCAP E2/TO/ETME2"
            val modifiedSrc = "C:/Software/SCAP E2/Modified CAFM files"
            includeDirs.headerFilterOnly(cafmSrc, scapSrc, modifiedSrc)
            extraOpts.add("-verbose")
        }
    }
    binaries {
        executable()
    }
}
```

This is my scape2.def file:

```
headers = scape2.h
headerFilter = scape2.h \ GEO_API_SCAPTO.h
linkerOpts.mingw = -LC:/Users/lscarmin/git/calculation-module4 -lscape2
```

I was expecting that the dll name to be scape2.dll.
But when I run the executable, it asks for ETME2.dll!
If I rename scape2.dll to ETME2.dll, the code works. (editado)

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems that the file name used is the one defined inside the dll. I have renamed the dll file, but the name used will be the original one.
I didn't know that this info was kept inside the dll